# Change css of a DOM element that does not have an id using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<div>` that is displayed and several `<p>` which are hidden inside that

```
<div class="em-booking-form-details">
<p class="ticket-price">
.........
.........
</div>
```

currently 
css is

```
.em-booking-form-details p{
    display:none;
}
```

i have a button register with id=register. when i click this button i want to be displayed all the `<p>` s . not that i cant use id for `<p>` and `<div>` and only use javascript.

Comment: But you can use jQuery for it or not? If so then $(document).on('click','#register',function()
{
$(".ticket-price").show()
});

Comment: He doesn't need jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I provided a solution on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L5Xsg/

```
var dom_elements = document.querySelectorAll('.em-booking-form-details p');
var dom_length = dom_elements.length;

console.log(dom_elements);
for(var i = 0 ; i < dom_length ; i++) {
    dom_elements[i].style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.querySelectorAll('.em-booking-form-details p')`

Will return a list of DOM nodes that match that CSS selector. You can iterate over that list and set the `display` property to `block` or whatever you need

Answer (score 1):

```
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName("em-booking-form-details")
    var p = div[0].getElementsByTagName('p')
    for(var i=0;i<p.length;i++){
            p[i].style.display = "block";       
    }   





    var p = document.getElementsByClassName('ticket-price')
    var all = p[0].parentElement.children
    for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++){
            all[i].style.display = "block";     
    }
```